# Magento 2.3 Installation worked on Ubuntu 18.04, but after Ubuntu Restart Magento Page will not load any more. Any Ideas what could be the Problem?

Tags: magento2.3, sql, apache2, ubuntu

I need your help. I am new to Magento 2.3 and first everything worked perfect after the Installation on my Ubuntu 18.04 Maschine, but after my first Ubuntu restart the Magento Shop Page and Admin Page arent loading any more.

My first thought was that Apache or SQL are not running, but i checked and they have the status active. But Apache2 throws some errors (you can find them in the screenshot). Could this errors be the problem and if so, how can i solve them?

[image]

If you dont think that this errors are the problem, do you have any other idea?

I would be very releaved if you could help me with this problem, because I already wasted to much time and effort with this Problem and a proper Magento 2.3 Installation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe a permission issue. check permission and also try to restart or reinstall the mysql

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, yes it was a permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a permission issue. So, give file permission to your generated/ pub/ var/ folders using following command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media pub/static
```

Comment: @felix Please check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much, that worked. But I only needed to change the permission of the var folder. Afterwards Apache2 and Magento 2.3 worked fine agian